# AlertDialog MultiChoice isn't giving me the correct selections

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to build a multichoice AlertDialog using dynamic data.

Ok, it's all loading great and etc, but the selections are messed up.

Here is my code:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Cities")
        .setMultiChoiceItems(_options, _selections, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked, boolean selected) {
                        Log.i("Database", _options[clicked] + " selected: " + selected);
                }

        })
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked) {
                    switch(clicked) {
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                            for( int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++ ){
                                Log.i("Database", "id: " + _values[i] + " " + _options[i] + " selected: " + _selections[i]);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
        })
        .create();
```

As you can see in the LogCat, I described my problem:

```
** OPENED ALERTDIALOG VIA A BUTTON AND SELECTED THE FOLLOWING: **
07-12 16:06:51.347: I/Database(8034): Aveiro selected: true
07-12 16:06:53.936: I/Database(8034): Coimbra selected: true
07-12 16:07:00.116: I/Database(8034): Porto selected: true

** AFTER PRESSING THE OK BUTTON, THIS SHOWS UP, WHICH IS CORRECT: **
07-12 16:07:02.826: I/Database(8034): id: 1 Aveiro selected: true
07-12 16:07:02.826: I/Database(8034): id: 2 Coimbra selected: true
07-12 16:07:02.826: I/Database(8034): id: 3 Porto selected: true
07-12 16:07:02.826: I/Database(8034): id: 4 Minho selected: false

** I CLICKED THE BUTTON TO START THE DIALOG AGAIN DE UNSELECTED THE FOLLOWING: **
07-12 16:07:07.087: I/Database(8034): Coimbra selected: false

** AFTER PRESSING THE OK BUTTON, ALL SHOWS AS FALSE. 1 AND 3 SHOULD BE TRUE: **
07-12 16:07:08.097: I/Database(8034): id: 1 Aveiro selected: false
07-12 16:07:08.097: I/Database(8034): id: 2 Coimbra selected: false
07-12 16:07:08.097: I/Database(8034): id: 3 Porto selected: false
07-12 16:07:08.097: I/Database(8034): id: 4 Minho selected: false
```

Comment: Where are you updating these arrays?

Comment: Which ones? If it is the `_selections`, it's automatically updated by the AlertDialog method `.setMultipleChoiceItems`. If you're asking for the others, they don't really matter for this issue, my only problem is with the `_selections` array.

Comment: Just tried your code and it is working fine for me. Added the code i used to test, so you can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Tried your code and it is working fine for me. Step through it and make sure your values are correct.

Here is my test app. The only difference is that i did not know what `_values` was, so i took it out.

```
public class SandBoxActivity extends Activity {

    private Button testButton;

    private CharSequence[] _options = {"Aveiro", "Coimbra", "Porto", "Minho"};

    private boolean[] _selections = {true, true, true, false};

    private AlertDialog test;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        test = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Cities")
        .setMultiChoiceItems(_options, _selections, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked, boolean selected) {
                        Log.i("Database", _options[clicked] + " selected: " + selected);
                }

        })
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked) {
                    switch(clicked) {
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                            for( int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++ ){
                                Log.i("Database", "id: " + " " + _options[i] + " selected: " + _selections[i]);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
        })
        .create();

        this.testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.color_button);
        this.testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                test.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**OLD POST**

```
.setMultiChoiceItems(_options, _selections, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked, boolean selected) {
                        Log.i("Database", _options[clicked] + " selected: " + selected);
                }

        })
```

I do not see that you are actually handling the fact that it was clicked. I see that you are printing to the log that it was clicked, but you are not changing the fact that it is selected in your `_selections` array. That could possibly be your problem.

**Try this:**

```
.setMultiChoiceItems(_options, _selections, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked, boolean selected) {
                        _selections[clicked] = selected;
                        Log.i("Database", _options[clicked] + " selected: " + selected);
                }

        })
```

Comment: It is handled automatically by the MultiChoiceItems (the param _selections is the one that gets automatically updated with the selected values). So, that workaround that you gave me doesn't do the job, as it gives me the exact same output...

Comment: I'm trying to debug the variable, but it does not show me any variables in the Variables Tab on Eclipse (Java EE, Juno). Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I'm on Mac...

Comment: Make sure you have the device selected that you are trying to debug and that you have the debug tree selected. Also, try restarting eclipse. Most of the time, restarting eclipse fixes that issue.

Comment: Where can I find the debug tree you're talking about? [Screenshot of my Eclipse](http://i.imgur.com/SHX0q.png)

Comment: You can also get the values by hovering your mouse above the variables while debugging

Comment: Debug tree may be the wrong word. I meant stack trace. lawls. Window -> Show View -> Debug -> Debug.

Comment: Did you finally find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Silentw,
Please read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMultiChoiceItems%28java.lang.CharSequence%5B%5D,%20boolean%5B%5D,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener%29)

We have to supply the boolean array for the selected options everytime it is created

Also update you code as follows

```
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked, boolean selected) 
{                      
                     if(!_selections[clicked])
                        _selections[clicked] = true;
                    else
                        _selections[clicked]=false;

                        Log.i("Database", _options[clicked] + " selected: " + selected);

}
```

Comment: The `_selections` array is automatically modified by the `.setMultiChoiceItems`, no need to be redundant by setting the `_selections[clicked] = true;` twice...